# Couchbase lite 2.0.0-DB021, Android, - OrderBy multiple columns?

Tags: android, sql-order-by, couchbase-lite

How can I translate the following `Orderby` sql statement to

> ORDER BY Country ASC, CustomerID DESC;

I have manage to write  `Ordering.property("Country").ascending();`
but not sure how to add the next condition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `orderBy` method, you will see that it has the following signature

```
public OrderBy orderBy(Ordering... orderings)
```

Note that you can put multiple `Ordering` objects inside.